# MS Excel VBA Macro Dynamic Range

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, range

Here Is a sample of the table (with creepy sample data)

```
|Col A       |Col B     |Col C   |Col D     |Col E
+------------+----------+--------+----------+-----
|Number      |Value     |X       |Date      |Decimal
|1           |        AA|X       |2012/01/01|.1
|2           |        BB|X       |2012/02/01|.2
|3           |        CC|X       |2012/03/01|.3
|4           |        DD|X       |2012/04/01|.4
|5           |        EE|X       |2012/05/01|.5
```

What needs to be done:

- Sort the table according to the "Value"(Col B in this instance) in a macro

Conditions:

- The header values DOES NOT change
- I have to search the headers which will contain the word "Value" since it changes from Col C to Col D or Col A... B... E...
- Column headers ALWAYS stay at 1st row

What I have done so far:

- Brute force the value...(BAD!)
- Search the header to find what column contains the header "Value"
- Get the column letter/number and store in a variable

Problems:

- Using the column letter or number as basis for sort.
  (i.e. Range (colLetter & ":" & colLetter))

Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Tester()

Const SORT_HEADER As String = "Value"
Dim sht As Worksheet, f As Range


    Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Set f = sht.Rows(1).Find(SORT_HEADER, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not f Is Nothing Then

        sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort _
            Key1:=sht.Columns(f.Column), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

    Else
        MsgBox "'" & SORT_HEADER & "' column not found!"
    End If

End Sub
```